# SwiftUI curve audio waveform

Tags: ios, swiftui

hi I would like to achieve this kind of UI

[image]

however so far I only manage to make it looks like this

[image]

here is my full code where I have tried to achieve this

```swift
struct Wave: Shape {
    var animatableData: Double {
        get { phase }
        set { self.phase = newValue }
    }

    var strength: Double
    var frequency: Double
    var phase: Double
    var curveAmount: Double

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()

        let width = Double(rect.width)
        let height = Double(rect.height)
        let midWidth = width / 2
        let midHeight = height / 2

        let start = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: midHeight)
        let end = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: midHeight)
        let control = CGPoint(x: midWidth, y: rect.minY + strength * curveAmount)

        path.move(to: start)

        for x in stride(from: 0, through: width, by: 1) {
            let progress = x / width
            let parabolicY = QuadBezier(t: progress, start: start.y, c: control.y, end: end.y)
            let sineWave = sin(progress * frequency * 2 * .pi + phase) * (strength * 0.5)
            let y = parabolicY + sineWave

            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        }

        return path
    }

    private func QuadBezier(t: Double, start: CGFloat, c: CGFloat, end: CGFloat) -> Double {
        let invT = 1 - t
        let b1 = 3 * t * (invT * invT)
        let b2 = 3 * (t * t) * invT
        let b3 = t * t * t

        let part1 = Double(start) * Double(invT * invT * invT)
        let part2 = Double(c) * Double(b1 + b2)
        let part3 = Double(end) * Double(b3)

        return part1 + part2 + part3
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var phase = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            ForEach(0..<20) { i in
                Wave(strength: 10, frequency: 4, phase: self.phase, curveAmount: 30)
                    .stroke(Color.white.opacity(Double(i) / 10), lineWidth: 5)
                    .offset(y: CGFloat(i) * 1.2)
            }
            Wave(strength: 10, frequency: 0, phase: 0, curveAmount: 30)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 5)
                .offset(y: 7 * 5)
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                self.phase = .pi * 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

does any one know how I can achieve this exact UI?

having hard time to achieve this. The UI will animate as the input from microphone sound and it will animate differently depending on the spectrum of the audio

Comment: Please describe exactly the desired characteristics of the output. What aspects of the expected result do you want to recreate? It is not practical to produce the "exact" same thing just by looking at a picture.

Comment: The "bumps" in the original picture appear to be built as stripes. Do you want it to be striped like this, or could it be a gradient over the full length?

Comment: Also, your example code is animated. Please could you describe, exactly how you want the animation to work?

Comment: Matching your exact UI is trivial, in just one line of code: `AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNhLH.png"))`. The question is "in what user-impacting way is my answer not sufficient (since obviously it isn't)?" What does this UI express to the user other than the image, and by what rules? When you know the rules, you'll have your algorithm.

Comment: Apologises if the description isn’t clear. It is supposed to be an audio waveform.  Therefore the animation moves as users speak and different spectrum will move depending of what sound is coming